# Comparing floating point numbers in VS C++ vs C++ Builder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I am working with some astronomy code originally compiled in Visual C++. I am compiling it in C++Builder XE4 on the 32bit VCL platform.

In this code, there are a lot of comparisons for very small numbers, all defined as `double`. The code snip below shows the headers and some sample comparisons from the VC++ code. I need the results to be the same in VC++ and C++ Builder, so I have some questions about comparing floating point numbers:

1. Does C++Builder compare floating point numbers the same as VC++?
2. In C++Builder, do I need to rewrite the code using the `CompareValue(double, double)` function?
3. Will I get the same result if I switch from `#include <cmath>` to using `#include <math.h>` and `#include <math.hpp>`?

Any suggestions for getting the same results in both compilers would be helpful.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

...
else if ((fgamma > 0.9972) && (fgamma < (1.5433 + details.u)))
{
  if ((fgamma > 0.9972) && (fgamma < (0.9972 + fabs(details.u))))
  {
    if (details.u < 0)
      ...
```

Comment: Comparisons are performed by the hardware, and independent of the compiler. You are also worrying too much about this. For instance, you can't even represent 0.9972 exactly as a floating point value. And if you care about precision, why do you only have 4 significant figures. It's awfully easy to get confused, engage in fuzzy thinking, and throw `CompareMath` at everything. Don't. Try to understand better. And finally, Q3 is staggering. It's not hard to find out what cmath is, and what math.h is. Do some research.

Comment: For Q1, you need to look at the actual compiled machine code to see what CPU instructions each compiler is actually using to compare floating-point values at runtime.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you don’t need all those parentheses. `if (gamma > 0.9972 && fgamma < 1.543 + details.u)` means exactly the same thing as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

1. No
2. Depends on the compiler settings in both + thread environment.
3. Yes, but see #2

**Long answer**

Compiler settings

The most important compiler setting is target instruction set. Depending on the setting, double-precision floating-point code can be compiled into legacy x87 instructions, to SSE2, or higher (SSE 4, AVX, etc.)
The funny thing is, some compilers with some settings compile into both. Within the same program, they may use x87 for one things, SSE for other things.

There’re are other relevant compiler switches, e.g. [`/fp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) in Visual C++

Thread environment

For x87 code, the interesting part of the thread state is x87 FPU control register. For Visual C++, see [_controlfp_s API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx).

SSE components of the CPU use similar thing, [MxCsr register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/mxcsr).